# Problem in solving quartic equations

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, galois-theory

There is only one step in Descartes' method for solving the quartic that confuses me.

Consider the depressed quartic $x^4+px^2+qx+r=0$, note I am assuming that the coefficients $p,q,r\in\mathbb{C}$. And let's assume $q\neq0$ so it's not biquadratic which is easy to solve.

Assuming that the quartic can be factorized as two quadratics, i.e., $$x^4+px^2+qx+r=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$$ $$=x^4+(a+c)x^3+(ac+b+d)x^2+(ad+bc)x+(bd)$$ Now by comparing the coefficiends, we have $c=-a$, so $$p+a^2=d+b$$ $$q=a(d-b)$$ $$r=bd$$ Since $q\neq0$ we have $a\neq0$, also $$2b=p+a^2-\frac{q}{a}$$ $$2d=p+a^2+\frac{q}{a}=p+c^2-\frac{q}{c}$$ Next we have $$a^2(p+a^2)^2-q^2=a^2((d+b)^2-(d-b)^2)=4a^2r$$ $$a^2(p+a^2)^2-q^2-4a^2r=0$$ Observe that $b,d$ disappeared in the above equation. Now let $A=a^2$, the above equation is a monic cubic in $A$ and the coefficients are in $p,q,r$, i.e., $$A^3+(2p)A^2+(p^2-4r)A+(-q^2)=0$$ Let the three roots of the above cubic be $A_1,A_2,A_3$. So we have six candidates for $a=\pm\sqrt{A_1},\pm\sqrt{A_2},\pm\sqrt{A_3}$, but since $c=-a$ and by looking at the forms of $b,d$, the $\pm$ only accounts for interchanging $(a,b)$ with $(c,d)$. Hence let's assume $a$ has only three possibilities $$a=\sqrt{A_1},\sqrt{A_2},\sqrt{A_3}$$

Here is my question:

I know the three possibilities for $a$ is only responsible for three different grouping on the four roots of the quartic, i.e., $$(\{x_1,x_2\},\{x_3,x_4\})$$ $$(\{x_1,x_3\},\{x_2,x_4\})$$ $$(\{x_1,x_4\},\{x_2,x_3\})$$

where $\{x_1,x_2\}$ are zeros of $x^2+ax+b$ and $\{x_3,x_4\}$ are zeros of $x^2+cx+d$.

But how does one prove this? Writing the complete formula for three different $a$'s is already an arduous work to do, so it seems impossible to do this by comparing the explicit formulas of $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$.